# Как преобразовать тип String в тип double?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, получаю на клиенте GPS координаты в типе String пользуясь для этого

```
String.format(
            "%1$.4f",
            location.getLongitude());
```

На сервере нужно положить их в таблицу с полями double. 
Пробовал не конвертируя получаю ошибку

```
Data truncated for column 'latitude' at row 1
```

Пробовал отправлять значения не используя String.format, но тогда приходят не вменяемо огромные шестнадцатеричные значения.
Пробовал использовать

```
longitude=Double.parseDouble(din.readUTF())
```

сервер не принимает значения.
Можно попробовать распарсить регулярками, но это добавит коду.

Может есть менее затратный вариант по преобразованию ?

Тип поля в таблице

Тип данных         DOUBLE 
Длина/значение     1,0

Comment: причем тут boolean?

Comment: @iksuy видимо должен быть `double`. Судя по `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: @iksuy да всё верно исправил.

Comment: а какой тип полей в базе?

Comment: @Komdosh double а приходит в  string

Comment: похоже на то, что у вас тип поля в базе данных имеет длину, недостаточную для сохранения координаты. добавьте тип поля в пост

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример String который вы хотите преобразовать в Double

Comment: @Ksenia добавил.

Comment: @Chubatiy добавил.

Comment: @VargSieg, так у вас поле имеет длину 1? Увеличьте её:
alter table имя_таблицы modify имя_колонки тип_колонки; вместо 1,0 поставьте, например, 10,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увеличьте размер поля в базе данных, например:

`alter table table_name alter column row_name DECIMAL(10,0);`

Comment: Запятую на точку как разделитель попробуйте изменить

Comment: Ошибку с точкой вместо запятой покажите, пожалуйста. И ещё. У вас в `SQL` запросе на `insert` случайно не экранировано значение поля ничем? К примеру `"'" +value+ "'"`?

Comment: @Chubatiy да вот запрос `"  INSERT INTO  entre (id, latitude ")" "VALUES('"+id+"', '"+latitude+"')"

Comment: @VargSieg, вроде как нужно как раз точку использовать

Comment: @VargSieg, и напишите ещё, пожалуйста, как выглядит ваша координата в строковом варианте

Comment: Беда может быть именно потому, что в тоге insert преобразуется в  `INSERT INTO entre (id, latitude) VALUES ('1', '90,1911')` вместо `INSERT INTO entre (id, latitude) VALUES ('1', 90.1911)`

Comment: и зачем тут два вида кавычек? `VALUES('"+id+"', '"+latitude+"')`

Comment: попробуйте убрать одни из них, например, `VALUES("+id+", "+latitude+")`

Comment: Храните тогда координаты без преобразования и преобразуйте в нужный вам формат на клиентской стороне